# Scala Monad - without for statement(elegant way to check null attribute)

Tags: java, scala, monads

Assuming i have just one top level object with another two object nested inside as attribute:

```
class Human(val name: String, val child: Human)

val anita = new Human("Anita", null)
val david = new Human("David", anita)
val fabrizio = new Human("Fabrizio", david)
```

if i have to get the last child's name starting to fabrizio i need to do a lot of null-check controls :

```
if(fabrizio != null)
    if(fabrizio.child!= null)
        if(fabrizio.children.child!= null)
            println(fabrizio.child.child.name)
```

i found this "syntactic sugar" on scala but it seems to work just with collections :

```
println( for(x <- fabrizio.child; y <- x.child; z <- y.child) yield z.name)
```

In fact it complains :

```
value flatMap is not a member of Playground.this.Human
```

Is there a way to get last child name without put the top level object in a Collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not exclusive to collections. Scalas for-comprehension desugars to nested `flatMap` calls and a final `map`. Instead of using `null` in your code, use an `Option[T]` to express the fact that a `Human` and it's children may or may not be defined:

```
final case class Human(name: String, children: Option[Human])
val maybeAnita: Option[Human] = Some(Human("Anita", None))
val maybeDavid: Option[Human] = Some(Human("David", maybeAnita))
val maybeFabrizio: Option[Human] = Some(Human("Fabrizio", maybeDavid))
```

Now you can:

```
val maybeName: Option[String] = for {
  fabrizio <- maybeFabrizio
  children <- fabrizio.children
  nestedChildren <- children.children
} yield nestedChildren.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Yuval's suggestion of using `Option` is the idiomatic, and simple, way of dealing with `null` and is a superb suggestion. I would like to add to this:

If you're looking for the name of the last child, you could simply create a function:

```
def lastChild(person: Human, isChild: Boolean = false): Option[Human] = {
    person.children match {
        case Some(child) => lastChild(child, true)
        case None if isChild => Some(person)
        case _ => None
    }
}
```

You could also add a level variable to ensure a certain generation:

```
def nthChild(person: Human, level: Int, isChild: Boolean = false): Option[Human] = {
    person.children match {
        case Some(child) if (level > 0) => lastChild(child, (level - 1), true)
        case _ if ((level == 0) && isChild) => Some(person)
        case _ => None
    }
}
```

---

On a side note: if each `Human` can only have one child, that field should be named `child` for clarity